# Disable Photo Booth sounds

Tags: macos, mojave, photo-booth

How do I stop Photo Booth.app making sounds on the countdown and on the capture?

Sounds like a "beep - beep - beep" countdown and a shutter sound for capture.

How do I mute the app?

Comment: Simply muting the computer while using the app wont do?

Comment: @Perry no bc I want other sounds to be playing, and it's annoying to mute the computer anyway

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it, it's frustrating and unnecessary sound

Comment: another classic case of apple UX "design" :/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible option for you:

Hold down Option key while clicking the camera button. It'll instantly take the picture and not use the screen flash, but it will be silent.